# Liferay: document load counter don't work on the Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.1.20 EE

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, difference

I have the portlet, that show documents with the top read ranking. It works perfectly on the 
Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.1 CE GA2, but its not works on another server with Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.1.20 EE.  Both servers have this property in portal-ext: dl.file.entry.read.count.enabled=true.

Does anyone have any ideas, what is diffrent in the EE version?

Thank you very much.

Sven

Answer (score 0):

Check this properties are true:

```
#
# Set this to true to enable file rank for document library files.
#
dl.file.rank.enabled=true

#
# Set this to true to enable the read count for document library files.
#
dl.file.entry.read.count.enabled=true

# Set this to true to enable incrementing the view counter for assets.
#
asset.entry.increment.view.counter.enabled=true
```

Comment: the properties are setted on both servers, but it still not works under EE version

Comment: Maybe is a bug, try to look for/asked in https://issues.liferay.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in Liferay EE which will be fixed in the next version

see https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-28644